# Error adding Google Maps with react - TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```js
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Map from "./Map.js"


class App extends React.Component {



  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loadScript = this.loadScript.bind(this);
  }

  loadScript() {

    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}&libraries=places`;

    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    this.loadScript();

  }


  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <Map />


      </div>


    );

  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
//Map.js

import React from "react"

export default class Map extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.loadMap = this.loadMap.bind(this);
    }

    loadMap() {

        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        this.loadMap();
    }


    render() {


        return (


            <div id="map" style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}></div>

        );

    }




}
```

Hi there, I am totally new to React, I am trying to load Google Maps without the help of a third-party library.

I have dynamically created a script tag and inserted it into the DOM. I am getting this error, trying to access the variables in the script.

My guess is that 'maps' is being accessed before the script is loaded. I am lost, on how to fix this error.

Comment: The solution on this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421602/html-script-is-loading-after-react-components) will fix your problem that is related to access google before google script is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a script programmatically you can listen for "onload" event and do the rest of your logic when the script will be loaded. In this case, your `loadScript` function might look like this:

```
loadScript() {

  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}&libraries=places`;

  const s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = url;
  document.head.appendChild(s);
  s.onload = function(e){
     console.info('googleapis was loaded');            
  }
}
```

You can add a `scriptLoaded` state to your App component and change it in the `onload` function, in this case, you need to render  only if `scriptLoaded` is `true` :

```
  <div>
    {this.state.scriptLoaded && <Map />}
  </div>
```

Comment: I get "A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. " error..

Only when I try to render the map `{this.state.isLoaded && <Map /> }` if I instead write `{this.state.isLoaded && <h1>True</h1> }` .. it Displays the heading.

Comment: In your <Map/> component you call the `loadMap` method in the `componentWillMount `, at that time your component wasn't rendered yet, try to change it to `componentDidMount`.